# Email sent using javax mail delivers with empty subject and to fields

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

I am sending emails from my application using the code below:

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
String encodingOptions = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
message.setHeader("Content-Type", encodingOptions);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmailAddress));
String[] toAddressArr = emailMsg.getTo().split(CommonConstants.SEMI_COLON);

for (String srtAddress : toAddressArr) {
    InternetAddress ia = new InternetAddress(srtAddress);
    addressToList.add(ia);
}

InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[addressToList.size()];
message.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressToList.toArray(addressTo));

if (!Util.isNullOrBlank(emailMsg.getCc())) {
    String[] copyAddressArr = emailMsg.getCc().split(CommonConstants.SEMI_COLON);
    ArrayList<InternetAddress> addressCopyList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String srtAddress : copyAddressArr) {
    InternetAddress ia = new InternetAddress(srtAddress);
    addressCopyList.add(ia);
}

InternetAddress[] addressCopy = new InternetAddress[addressCopyList.size()];
message.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.CC, addressCopyList.toArray(addressCopy));
}

if (!Util.isNullOrBlank(emailMsg.getBcc())) {
    String[] bccAddressArr = emailMsg.getBcc().split(CommonConstants.SEMI_COLON);
    ArrayList<InternetAddress> addressBccList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String srtAddress : bccAddressArr) {
        InternetAddress ia = new InternetAddress(srtAddress);
        addressBccList.add(ia);
    }

    InternetAddress[] addressBcc = new InternetAddress[addressBccList.size()];
    message.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.BCC, addressBccList.toArray(addressBcc));
}

    message.setSubject(emailMsg.getSubject(), "UTF-8");
    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setText(emailMsg.getMessage());
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }
}
```

With the codes above, I get the email delivered to the recipient email addresses, however, the subject field is empty, the to field is empty as well while all recipients are shown in the bcc field of the email. Also, the attachment comes in as a byte string instead of a downloadable pdf file.
Here is a sample of what comes in:

> user@gmail.com to bcc:  user@outlook.com, bcc: user@domain.com
>
> ------=_Part_0_455461077.1587067667930 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>
> Dear Sir,
>
> STATUS REPORT
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> For further inquiries, kindly contact our customer services Unit on
>   any of the following numbers: 01-255xxxx and 01-270xxxx.
>
> Kind Regards. For XYZ Corp.
>   ------=_Part_0_455461077.1587067667930 Content-Type: text/plain; name=37855.pdf Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition:
>   attachment; filename=37855.pdf
>
> JVBERi0xLjMKJcTl8uXrp/Og0MTGCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwgL0xlbmd0aCA1IDAgUiAvRmlsdGVyIC9G
>   bGF0ZURlY29kZSA+PgpzdHJlYW0KeAHNXW1v5EZy/s5fQY9mdmbXEocvwzet5PPKu7eO42ziWInv
>   EOWTkcshsANc/P+BPNX1VL+QlMTROkBgYKludldX13tXF8d/y3/I/5b3dT7mp27M6z7/n//If8r/
>   Oz9+81uV//xbXrr/fvsZo8qiPmlb/qiGvB2aYqzzn3/N7+6zq7IoS/Tf/wxIbhge1Vi1RdlV+VXd
>   1F1+/2t+vL+v8yq//0v+b/nhi83r/KrKDxf62Opj9zr79/z+u/zDvUPuyWWjteqyORVD06drZW6t
>   ...

My intention is to deliver the email with html formatting, however, I'm unable to proceed with that objective as I am being held back by this show stopper. 
Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I'm attaching a pdf file to be sent as an email attachment with the code below:

```
if (attachments != null) {  
        for (EmailAttachmentData attachment : attachments) {
            MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(attachment.getData(),      
            attachment.getFileType());
            attachPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            attachPart.setFileName(attachment.getFileName());
            multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
        }
    }

    message.setContent(multipart);
    message.setSentDate(new Date());

    try {
        Transport transport = session.getTransport(mailProtocol);
        transport.connect(mailHost, Integer.parseInt(mailPort), userName, password);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is my maven dependency definition for javax mail

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my own problem by excluding geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec and geronimo-activation_1.1_spec from some of my maven dependencies. I also had multiple javax.mail-api and javax.mail dependencies, hence removing the duplicates saved the day. Everything now works well. Subject and to fields are populated well and attachments are properly sent as well. For clarity sake, I post the exclusions I made below:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.8</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-activation_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.8</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-activation_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-dom</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.8</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-activation_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of JavaMail are you using?

Your recipient code looks fine, although much more verbose than necessary.
But your content code is all wrong.

A message with an attachment is a message with a multipart content, which has one body part containing the main message content and another body part containing the attachment.

Your code about doesn't show how you're actually sending the message.
Are you just calling Transport.send?

Comment: I've edited my question to show how I add the attachment as well as my maven dependency definition for javax mail

Comment: I see that you're using the GNU version of JavaMail.  That's probably the source of the problem.  Switch to the [JavaMail (now known as Jakarta Mail) reference implementation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/#Download_Jakarta_Mail_Release) and it will probably work much better.

Comment: thanks @Bill Shannon, I'll definitely checkout Jakarta mail. Would let you know however it goes